# How to create a table from json encoded data from RestAPI?

Tags: android, json, wordpress

I am trying to create a simple table on MainActivity from json data from wordpress RestAPI. I have been able to get the "title" and "id". But I am having problems constructing a table.

The json data looks loke:

```
{
"id": 807,
"date": "2018-08-18T19:06:52",
"date_gmt": "2018-08-18T13:36:52",
"guid": {
    "rendered": "http://wordpresssite.com/?page_id=807"
},
"modified": "2019-04-27T14:32:50",
"modified_gmt": "2019-04-27T09:02:50",
"slug": "sample-post",
"status": "publish",
"type": "page",
"link": "http://wordpresssite.com/sample-page/",
"title": {
    "rendered": "Test results"
},
"content": {
    "rendered": "<div class=\"entry\">\n<p>Check out <strong>Current data</strong> &amp; <strong>Previous Data</strong> here. Among the others, <strong>data</strong> usually is declared first. This page is entirely dedicated to update you with <strong>test data</strong>.</p>\n</script></p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<h2 style=\"text-align: center;\">data</h2>\n\n<table id=\"tablepress-5\" class=\"tablepress tablepress-id-5\">\n<thead>\n<tr class=\"row-1 odd\">\n\t<th class=\"column-1\">Date</th><th class=\"column-2\">First Round</th><th class=\"column-3\">Second Round</th>\n</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody class=\"row-hover\">\n<tr class=\"row-2 even\">\n\t<td class=\"column-1\">09/05/19</td><td class=\"column-2\">98</td><td class=\"column-3\">21</td>\n</tr>\n<tr class=\"row-3 odd\">\n\t<td class=\"column-1\">08/05/19</td><td class=\"column-2\">32</td><td class=\"column-3\">91</td>\n</tr>\n<tr class=\"row-4 even\">\n\t<td class=\"column-1\">07/05/19</td><td class=\"column-2\">74</td><td class=\"column-3\">87</td>\n</tr>\n<tr class=\"row-5 odd\">\n\t<td class=\"column-1\">05/05/19</td><td class=\"column-2\">20</td><td class=\"column-3\">27</td>\n</tr>\n<tr class=\"row-6 even\">\n\t<td
```

This is how I did for title:

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            gson = new Gson();
            list = (List) gson.fromJson(s, List.class);
            postTitle = new String[list.size()];

            for(int i=0;i<list.size();++i){
                mapPost = (Map<String,Object>)list.get(i);
                mapTitle = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("title");
                postTitle[i] = (String) mapTitle.get("rendered");
            }

            postList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,postTitle));

        }
    },
```

Comment: what kind of problem your facing?

Comment: How to extract table data from the "content". It is not the same as extracting "title".

Comment: which parser you are using?

Comment: Gson with volley

Comment: can add your api response class?

Comment: Sorry, could not understand you question. Is this you are looking [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_response/)

Comment: how to you parse your json ? can you that code in your question?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: you are trying to convert json object to list. am I right? or your response is json array?

Comment: Actually sir, There is a table in the "content" of the json. I want to display the in information on a TableView.

Comment: actually it's html content,so use webview

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below approach to design your tabular view. You can dynamically create the view based on your json data.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TableRow
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <TableRow
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >



        </TableRow>
    </TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"

    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=" Date "
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Miles "
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
      />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Calories"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_column="2"
       />
</TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text=" Text"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text=" Text"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text=" Text"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_column="2" />
    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Actually I am having problems to extract the table data from "content" section of the json response. How do we do that?

Comment: Better you can use Gson library to parse your json data. you can use it like below: Gson gson = new Gson();
         
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
        SearchResponse response = gson.fromJson(reader, SearchResponse.class); You can follow the below link to implement the Gson parsing [Gson parsing](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

Comment: I am using gson. Successfully parsed "id" and "title". How to extract table data from the "content"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use JSOUP library to parse your html content.

Answer (score 0):

I am expecting below content as your input:

```
{
    "id": 807,
    "date": "2018-08-18T19:06:52",
    "date_gmt": "2018-08-18T13:36:52",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "http://wordpresssite.com/?page_id=807"
    },
    "modified": "2019-04-27T14:32:50",
    "modified_gmt": "2019-04-27T09:02:50",
    "slug": "sample-post",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "page",
    "link": "http://wordpresssite.com/sample-page/",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "Test results"
    },
    "content": {
        "rendered": "your content...."
    }
}
```

Now you can parse this data by following below:

1) Add dependency in your gradel file

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

2) Create pojo classes:

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Content.java-----------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Content {

@SerializedName("rendered")
@Expose
private String rendered;

public String getRendered() {
return rendered;
}

public void setRendered(String rendered) {
this.rendered = rendered;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("date")
@Expose
private String date;
@SerializedName("date_gmt")
@Expose
private String dateGmt;
@SerializedName("guid")
@Expose
private Guid guid;
@SerializedName("modified")
@Expose
private String modified;
@SerializedName("modified_gmt")
@Expose
private String modifiedGmt;
@SerializedName("slug")
@Expose
private String slug;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private String type;
@SerializedName("link")
@Expose
private String link;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private Title title;
@SerializedName("content")
@Expose
private Content content;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getDate() {
return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
this.date = date;
}

public String getDateGmt() {
return dateGmt;
}

public void setDateGmt(String dateGmt) {
this.dateGmt = dateGmt;
}

public Guid getGuid() {
return guid;
}

public void setGuid(Guid guid) {
this.guid = guid;
}

public String getModified() {
return modified;
}

public void setModified(String modified) {
this.modified = modified;
}

public String getModifiedGmt() {
return modifiedGmt;
}

public void setModifiedGmt(String modifiedGmt) {
this.modifiedGmt = modifiedGmt;
}

public String getSlug() {
return slug;
}

public void setSlug(String slug) {
this.slug = slug;
}

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public String getType() {
return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

public String getLink() {
return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
this.link = link;
}

public Title getTitle() {
return title;
}

public void setTitle(Title title) {
this.title = title;
}

public Content getContent() {
return content;
}

public void setContent(Content content) {
this.content = content;
}

}
--------------com.example.Guid.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Guid {

@SerializedName("rendered")
@Expose
private String rendered;

public String getRendered() {
return rendered;
}

public void setRendered(String rendered) {
this.rendered = rendered;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Title.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Title {

@SerializedName("rendered")
@Expose
private String rendered;

public String getRendered() {
return rendered;
}

public void setRendered(String rendered) {
this.rendered = rendered;
}

}
```

3) Parse data using Gson library and get the result:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

String stringToParse =""; //string you want to parse.

Example response = gson.fromJson(stringToParse , Example.class);

Content content = response.getContent();
```

Hope this will help to you.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. But there is a TablePress Table in the "content". I need that table data to display in TableView.

Comment: I think you want to fetch html content from your string. For this better you can use [JSOP](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-parse-html-pages-on-android-with-jsoup-2a9b0da0096f) parsing to parse and fetch the content. It is little bit difficult to fetch the html content, but you need to put extra effort to parse the content. Happy Coding.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was thinking the same.